# RavenDB: Adding documents from weakly-typed objects

Tags: ravendb, weakly-typed

I'm trying to figure out how to insert weakly-typed objects as RavenDB documents.

For example, I would like to insert a Datatable as a document:

- Each row is mapped to a single document
- The columns are mapped keys in the document
- The entire Datatable is a collection of documents of the same schema

Although the data is in a Datatable, it doesn't fit a relational DB, and the proper use would be in a NoSQL DB.
I have a lot of different Datatables with different schemas, and I do not want to create a representing class for each table manually.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dynamic class where each column is a field and then, using reflection, create a new object of the dynamic type and map Row[Col_Name] to obj.Col_Name.
After you create the object store it in the session.

Comment: That's what we did eventually.

Answer (score 2):

KellyG,
You can do that using a format such as this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Children {get;set;}

}
```

That would serialize cleanly into RavenDB, and you can then query / load / modify things easily

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is the Item in the class definition and the Item in the Dictionary is the same type? if so, why? 2. Wouldn't a serialization of this class create a document with a single key in the root level? I would like that all the "columns" would be keys in the root level of the document.